# Run ping command in discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py, ping

I know it has been solved like a million of times, but none of the current answers can help me.

This is how I configured the bot:

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
    
bot = commands.Bot(intents=discord.Intents.all(), command_prefix="-", description="A simply well made bot...")
```

and this is the command's code:

```py
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send(f'Pong! In {round(bot.latency * 1000)}ms')
```

Comment: And what happens when you do this?  What's your question?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There is no such an error.. the command simply does not run

Comment: Have you actually run the bot (logged in with the token etc) later in the code

Comment: Yeah, the bot runs perfectly, but the command does not run itself